# How to get the port of a remote actor when it was dynamically set?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor, remote-actors

I'm new to remote actors and I'm facing a problem. I need to set the port of my actors dynamically (or I have some problems with addresses already in use in my tests) but I don't find how to get the port that has been set.

I work with Play! scala. I thought I could get the port by a Play! controller like this (although it doesn't seem to be the proper way):

```
def remoteActorsPort = Action.async { implicit request =>
  implicit val timeout: akka.util.Timeout = 3.seconds
  val saveEventActor = actorSystem.actorSelection("/user/save-event-actor")
  saveEventActor ? WhatMyPort() map { maybePort =>
    maybePort.asInstanceOf[Option[Int]] match {
      case Some(port) => Ok(Json.toJson(port))
      case _ => NotFound
    }
  }
}
```

And in my actor:

```
case whatMyPort: WhatMyPort => sender ! self.path.address.port
```

But `self.path.address.port` **returns None**.

How can I proceed to get the port of a remote actor when it has been dynamically set?

Comment: How did you setup `actorSystem`?  To me it doesn't even look like you are using remoting here hence the `None` on the port on that actor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure to understand you question but I have in the application.conf of my Play! app: `akka.actor.provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"` .
And IMHO, I'm using remoting since I can access an actor created in an other Play! application with `context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2552/user/organizer-actor")`. (But here the port is hardly set [2552] and not dynamically.)